# Getting user friends, Subquery, Performance

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have two tables: `User` and `User2Friend`. I need to get user's friends. Query should handle two columns as FriendId: `FriendId` and `UserId` because we don't know who added whom. In result both are friends.

The query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    `Id`
    , `UserName`
FROM `User`
WHERE `Id` IN
    (SELECT
        IF(`UserId` = 25, `FriendId`, `UserId`) -- This important part - friends are always mutual
    FROM `User2Friend`
    WHERE `UserId` = 25
    OR `FriendId` = 25)
LIMIT 10
```

The schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `User` (
  `Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `UserName` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
CREATE TABLE `User2Friend` (
  `Id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `UserId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `FriendId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UserIdFriendId` (`UserId`, `FriendId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

If user A added user B as friend, user B appears in user A friend list, after that user B must have user A in friend list too. I don't really like subquery approach because I cannot use LIMIT in sub-select.

I'm expecting few millions of users, so performance is important.

Do you think it would be better to split this query to two separate ones?

Or maybe I need to have tricky JOIN?

Comment: can you put the structure of your table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay! I have split it to two queries...

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql1 = ("SELECT Id, UserName FROM User WHERE UserId = 25");
foreach($sql1 as $row){
    $id     = $row['Id'];
    $name   = $row['UserName'];
        $sql2 = ("SELECT * FROM User2Friend WHERE FriendId = $id LIMIT 10");
        foreach($sql2 as $row){
            $FriendId   = $row['FriendId'];
            $FriendName = $row['FriendName'];
        }
}
```

I do not know if I understood well but see if this solves the problem.

Comment: 1. Your example is wrong because you select first for Id 25 instead of all friend Ids. 2. Actually, you have to take into account two columns from look-up table: FriendId and UserId. Depending who added whom...

Answer (score 0):

You create a third field (Accepted) in the User2Friend table with the default value (N) when A adding friend B it will be able to list this friends and can confirm (S) and accept the friendship.

Comment: Not needed to add such field as `User2Friend` table has accepted friends.